# How to create a table with CSS

Tags: css, html-table

I want to [similar](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/).

1. How can I select first line?
2. How can I create double system?

Shortly I want to create beautiful tables but how?

If you have nice tutorial please share with me..

EDIT: Sorry my first language is not English. Double system mean for example:

```
second line : blue 
third line : red 
fourth line : blue
...
```

Comment: What mark-up are you working with; and what's a 'double system'?

Comment: You want "to similar"... similar to what? There's 10 examples in that link!

Comment: The CSS for what you want is pretty easy. Something like: `table { similar: true; first-line: selected; double-system: created; nice-tutorial: shared; }`

Comment: sorry my first language is not english. double system mean for example: second line : blue  - third line : red fourth line : blue....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select the first row of a table, you can do this using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$("table:first > tr:first")
```

To manipulate the css of that row you can use the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
var css = $("table:first > tr:first").css();
```

or

```
$("table:first > tr:first").css("color","red");
```

or

```
var cssObj = {
  'background-color' : 'Blue',
  'font-weight' : '',
  'color' : 'Black'
}

 $("table:first > tr:first").css(cssObj);
```

Using only CSS you can try using the [:nth-child](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild) pseudo-class selector:

```
tr:nth-child(1) {
  brackground-color: Blue;
  color: Yellow;
}

tr:nth-child(2) {
  brackground-color: Yellow;
  color: Green;
}

tr:nth-child(3) {
  brackground-color: Red;
  color: White;
}
```